# Cannot instantiate prefab when trying to in websocket message event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Websocket-Sharp to do this.

This code works when I use it but I can't because I need it to happen once a WebSocket message is received

```
static void NewPlayer(String name) 
    {
        GameObject player = Instantiate((GameObject) Resources.Load("Player Model"), Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        player.name = name;
        return;
    }

private void Start()
    {
        ws = new WebSocket("wss://servantchild-isu-game-2021.herokuapp.com");
        ws.Connect();
        NewPlayer("Name");
    }
```

Doesn't work when I use the code (I also know that the event fires and that the actual method is called but the prefab won't instantiate)

```
static void NewPlayer(String name) 
        {
            GameObject player = Instantiate((GameObject) Resources.Load("Player Model"), Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            player.name = name;
            return;
        }
private void Start()
    {
        ws = new WebSocket("wss://servantchild-isu-game-2021.herokuapp.com");
        ws.Connect();
        ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
        {
    if (e.Data.StartsWith("Player Joined:"))
            {
                NewPlayer(Int32.Parse(e.Data.Split(':')[1]).ToString());
            }
    };
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The event `OnMessage` might be coming in on a different thread.

Most of the Unity API is not "thread-safe" and may only be used on the Unity main thread.

You can use a dispatcher pattern like e.g.

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

...

// A thread-safe Queue (first in first out)
private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Action> _actions = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>(); 

GameObject playerPrefab; 

private void Start()
{
    playerPrefab = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Player Model");

    ws = new WebSocket("wss://servantchild-isu-game-2021.herokuapp.com");
    ws.Connect();
    ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Debug.Log($"Received: {e.Data}");
        if (e.Data.StartsWith("Player Joined:"))
        {
            // Do the expensive stuff still in a separate thread/task
            var value = Int32.Parse(e.Data.Split(':')[1]).ToString();
            // Dispatch into the Unity main thread's next Update routine
            _actions.Enqueue(() => NewPlayer(value));
        }
    };
}

private void Update ()
{
    // Work the dispatched actions on the Unity main thread
    while(_actions.Count > 0)
    {
        if(_actions.TryDequeue(out var action))
        {
            action?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}

private static void NewPlayer(string name) 
{
    var player = Instantiate(playerPrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
    player.name = name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first answer success!
Remember to use `Concurrent` namespace, insert:

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
```

and repace `_action` to `_actions` to work.

Answer (score -1):

Is this socket system multithreaded? if it is you need treadsafe system.

Comment: I don't think that websocket-sharp is multithreaded [Websocket-sharp multi-thread github issue](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp/issues/338)

Comment: Okay than did you try to instantiate player without if condition?